# Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page."

Tags: sql-server, import

I'm trying to import a text file in my mssql database via SSMS import utility and it's throwing below error:

```
    Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data 
conversion for column "Notes" returned status value 4 and status text 
"Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target 
code page.".
```

Suggested solutions available on internet, I have changed the code page to 65001(UTF-8). However, after updating that,I'm getting this new error:

```
    Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "LastName" cannot be 
processed because more than one code page (65001 and 1252) are specified 
for it.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Also, 'Edit Mappings' section isn't allowing me to increase column size as well.

[image]
any help will be appreciated in order to import my file

Here is the sample data which I want to import:
        EmployeeID,LastName,FirstName,BirthDate,Photo,Notes
    1,Davolio,Nancy,1968-12-08,EmpID1.pic,Education includes a BA in psychology 
    from Colorado State University. She also completed (The Art of the Cold 
    Call). Nancy is a member of 'Toastmasters International'.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. Either your column declared in your dataflow is too small for small for the column `Notes`, or the destination column in your database is too small.

Comment: @Larnu, import/export wizard is not allowing me to edit destination column size or else I'm not getting the proper option

Comment: If you've created your table already you won't be able to edit it in there; you need to use an `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Comment: @Larnu, I didn't create a table. Please understand, I'm importing data from a flat file,on the basis of that the table will get created. It's screenshot of import/export wizard column mappings

Comment: The table clearly exists, as the option "Create destination table" is greyed out.

Comment: @Larnu -I can't see the table in my database, It's not there. This is first time I'm creating this.

Comment: @Larnu - I'm using developer edition -https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: What do you mean "you can't see it"? As in, in your object explorer? Have you refreshed it? My statement doesn't change though, that table already exists in your database.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To import to a new table enter the name of the destination table (the one that will be created) for the Destination field and make sure there isn't already a table with this name in the database.  Once a new name is entered, you can make modifications to the destination columns on the Column Mappings window that appears after the Edit Mappings button is pressed.  In the following example, the name `NewTableName` was typed into this destination field and this will be the destination table.  If you're having trouble locating the table in the destination database make sure the correct database is selected on the `Choose a Destination` page of the Import and Export Wizard.  This is equivalent to the Initial Catalog property of a connection string, and you'll see the selected database there for the connection manager of the destination if you save the package and open it in SSDT.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for everyone else who gets this error but is not quite in the same situation that the OP is in. It seemed like I was genuinely having an issue with one field in one row being *too large* for the import data flow. Even though my column was large enough to receive the data in the "Column Mappings" page, the SSIS package still failed because "text was truncated" . . .

**My answer**:

1. Go to the "Choose  a Data Source" page.
2. Click on the "Advanced" tab on the left.
3. Choose the offending column.
4. Increase the **OutputColumnWidth** for that column. Below I have changed if from the default 50 to my column size, 1024.
   [image: "Choose a Data Source" page, advanced tab]
   Hope that helps. It fixed the issue for me instantly. Note that I figured this out based on [this post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/flat-file-import-tasks-fail-with-error-0xc02020a1#post-1822230).